# HTML: Trying to lower this box

Tags: html

I am attempting to create a simple box for my website, but I want to move it a bit lower down the page. How do I do that? Thank-you. Below is what i'm doing.

```
div {
    background-color: #BA75FF;
    width: 650 px;
    padding: 250px;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean a bit lower? The question is not clear without context. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what else is going on, but you can certainly just add more top margin:

```
div {
    ...
    margin: 100px 25px 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following:

`margin-top:100px;`

`position:absolute; top:100px;`